# How to select a single Curve in a Path in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I need to distinctly select a single Curve of a clicked Path, how can I do that?

For example, in [this sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dVJbS8MwFP4rh76shdHNeYOJT/oqCAo+OB/S5nSNS3NKcroxxv67J+tuoiu0JPmunHSTONVgMk3eFshlnQyTknTcL5WHZm2NQ3gEhyt4VVynuwUZx+nVeDwE+WTZw8zPXE/NA3ta4BNZ8iIbeNSDP+iH0VwLeheRM1RpfeY/OfpfptxFyv2eMhpBQIslAzm7Bq5NgLLzS4QCeYXoQBUkO+W0nFhaCX3eoONwMeD6GAAXOTcT4Uxu9yXiW3WuZENOerxQF/CZVi7FpSRlm4iDPLVhmUCrWvR56+lbaudy9o6Be2reRvfswC/JBbKYW5r/i5sqFfnJf5+RG8Ym78eCWhLZd3jgbAFtQPilkSE6YtDYa4ybg7IWqIgNA1RyraVV3vD6XHW43lNOpcT6GBQXW/m1Co9qsSsekunn1/YH) we can select a whole path when clicked on it:

[image]

Currently I can detect the curve (not sure if it is the appropriate approach, anyway):

```
..onMouseDown = (event) ~>
    hit = scope.project.hitTest event.point
    if hit?item
        # select only that specific segment
        curves = hit.item.getCurves!
        nearest = null
        dist = null
        for i, curve of curves
            _dist = curve.getNearestPoint(event.point).getDistance(event.point)
            if _dist < dist or not nearest?
                nearest = i
                dist = _dist

        selected-curve = curves[nearest]
            ..selected = yes
```

But whole path is selected anyway:

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier way to achieve what you want.
You can know if hit was on a curve by checking its [location](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult/#location) property.
If it is set, you can easily get the curve points and manually draw your selection.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) demonstrating it.

[image]

```
var myline = new Path(new Point(100, 100));
myline.strokeColor = 'red';
myline.strokeWidth = 6;
myline.add(new Point(200, 100));
myline.add(new Point(260, 170));
myline.add(new Point(360, 170));
myline.add(new Point(420, 250));

function onMouseDown(event) {
    hit = paper.project.hitTest(event.point);

    // check if hit is on curve
    if (hit && hit.location) {
        // get curve
        var curve = hit.location.curve;
        // draw selection
        var selection = new Group(
            new Path.Line({
                from: curve.point1,
                to: curve.point2,
                strokeColor: 'blue',
                strokeWidth: 3
            }),
            new Path.Rectangle({
                from: curve.point1 - 5,
                to: curve.point1 + 5,
                fillColor: 'blue'
            }),
            new Path.Rectangle({
                from: curve.point2 - 5,
                to: curve.point2 + 5,
                fillColor: 'blue'
            })
        );
        // make it automatically be removed on next down event
        selection.removeOnDown();
    }
}
```

### Update

As an alternative, to avoid messing up with the exported drawing, you can simply select the line instead of applying it a stroke style.
See this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jZNRT4MwEMe/yoWHDZKl21BnwuKTPmo00cQH50PXHoJAS0phLsu+u21xGzBjvISm9H73v7se7DxBC/Qi7zlDzRJv4jHJ7XtDFRTbPBUINyBwA09UJ77byFRofz6bTcAsQbBcqZVoUVJpJTO8lblUJmyskI/P3a8p14lxL7ouynlHPfxVfcAsLHP9J3PxD+YyNEx4dWDsE9eC6VQKkOJB1hXeyY3wsUGhA9hZAIwlqTZNlLRERUolP5FpYs5esNItS0qrf1K1QdMpsARZBmnsBNLK5ABWqwYPiPH41jUaWYLkklFbSyfzj9AH6n6kNTs3d2hq64YTd7gcSHBFN1Bhjq7doc7R0fkEyL25Qb9XirVYySJqE7dtzydDRMseEJ4BbTrkEWhV95raB8PCC5ohmEuitZaFaZDRPN/CGkFhIRvk9lYFfmngZnTgxtFVOHZGWv5RuBGf0uztxi3ml1grpJkruvKit/f9Nw==).

[image]

```
var selection = new Path.Line({
    from: curve.point1,
    to: curve.point2,
    selected: true
});
```

Comment: That's a very nice workaround. However, since this is not a selection, an extra care must be take while exporting the drawing.

Comment: Even better in terms of styling. However although it's invisible, the `new Path.Line` might be included on export. This can be easily prevented on export step by deleting those transient lines. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize that it will provide the specific curve that was hit - makes discovery quite a bit more elegant.

Comment: This approach has many problems: Manually drawn line's thickness changes visually when `view.zoom` is changed (original selections' thickness stays always the same). Moreover, moving the underlying curve (or segment, similarly) requires handling the  workaround movement separately. Moreover, `getNext()`, `getPrevious()` methods can not be used. Bug report: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1588

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do what you'd like AFAIK.

You basically need to walk through the segments, construct a line, and see if the hit is on that particular line. The line cannot be transparent or it's not considered a hit which is why I give it color and width to match the visible line; it's also why it's deleted after the test.

Here's the sketch [solution](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) that implements a bit more around this:

```
function onMouseDown(event){
    if (!myline.hitTest(event.point)) {
        return
    }
    c1.remove()
    c2.remove()
    // there's a hit so this should find it
    let p = event.point
    let segs = myline.segments
    for (let i = 1; i < segs.length; i++) {

        let line = new Path.Line(segs[i - 1].point, segs[i].point)
        line.strokeWidth = 6
        line.strokeColor = 'black'
        if (line.hitTest(p)) {
            c1 = new Path.Circle(segs[i-1].point, 6)
            c2 = new Path.Circle(segs[i].point, 6)
            c1.fillColor = 'black'
            c2.fillColor = 'black'
            line.remove()
            return
        }
        line.remove()
    }
    throw new Error("could not find hit")
}
```

Here's what I draw:

[image]